# Sequence and Run Query Examples

Tags: search, f#, design-patterns, sequence, repeat

I'd like to get some pointers and /or sample code on how to use F#/functional programming to search for repeating values in a list.

Consider the following Use Case: 
Given a list/array/sequence of dates and max temperatures for each date I'd like to extract out the initial dates on which them temp is greater than a given threshold for n consecutive days.

Another example of this type of query would be to search a stock price history table/list for prices over a given threshold that remained there for a specified interval (e.g. at least 30 days).
In this case I'm looking for the initial date when the threshold was first exceeded.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I like the succinctness of Tomas' code, I can't help but think that the more efficient version he hinted at is really mandatory here, especially if the actual comparison logic is ever more expensive than a simple integral comparison. I submit the following abstraction:

```
let findWindowBeginnings predicate minWindowSize data =
    if minWindowSize < 2 then
        invalidArg "minWindowSize" "minWindowSize must be greater than 1"

    ((None, []), data)
    ||> Seq.fold (fun (window, acc) x ->
        if predicate x then
            match window with
            | Some (start, size) -> let size' = size + 1
                                    let acc' = if size' = minWindowSize
                                               then start::acc
                                               else acc
                                    Some (start, size'), acc'
            | _                  -> Some (x, 1), acc
        else None, acc)
    |> snd
    |> List.rev
```

Your use case of a sequence of date+temperature tuples would look like:

```
let findHeatwaveBeginnings tempThreshold consecutiveDays data =
    (consecutiveDays, data)
    ||> findWindowBeginnings (snd >> (<) tempThreshold)
    // alternatively, if you're not a fan of point-free style code:
    //  findWindowBeginnings (fun (_, maxTemp) -> maxTemp > tempThreshold)
    |> List.map fst
```

Because `findWindowBeginnings` is driven by `Seq.fold`, it will of course work naturally with arrays and lists. Also, `findWindowBeginnings` is completely agnostic regarding the data type being examined, as the predicate you pass in does the data extrospection and the predicate can of course work on whatever data type you like (tuples, records, proper classes/structs, etc.). The only requirement is that the input data is logically sorted.

F# Snippets link: http://fssnip.net/3u

Comment: +1 for actually implementing it! Would you mind posting it to http://fssnip.net? People often ask similar questions and reading folds is much easier with type tooltips :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start with a less efficient, but elegant functional solution that uses the `Seq.windowed` function (which turns sequence into sequence of consecutive groups of specified size):

```
source
// Create groups of specified size
|> Seq.windowed requiredLength
// Add starting indices to the sequence
|> Seq.mapi (fun i v -> i, v)
// Find all groups that contain only numbers larger than treshold
|> Seq.filter (fun (i, v) -> v |> Seq.forall ((<) treshold))
// Get indices of such groups
|> Seq.map fst
```

This returns indices all such groups, so if there are multiple overlapping groups (i.e. a larger sequence matching the condition) then you'll get all starting indices. You could probably just filter consecutive numbers from the result to get only the first index of a group (using `Seq.fold`).

To get a more efficient version, you'll need to write a recursive function that iterates over the array or list. You'd probably need to remember (in a function argument) when you found a last value over the treshold. (This is essentially the same as imperative loop, except you use recursive function and keep state in arguments).